# WCF Routing Service, forward response to another service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-routing

We are planning to use the WCF Routing Service.

Imagine we have two queues (q1, q2), Routing service picks up the message from q1, forwards it to a request-reply service, once the response is receive by routing service, it forwards it again to q2.

We are stuck now on how we will forward the response to another queue, is this a possible Use Case in WCF RoutingService?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The Routing Service uses MessageFilter definitions that define specific attributes of a message exchange, such as the address, endpoint name, or even specific XPath statements for full content-based routing.

The following MSDN link provides a comprehensive overview of routing service message filter definition:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517424.aspx

Comment: So how does this help the OP with their problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly there is no way to achieve what you want to do.

The router can receive message A and forward it onto a req-reply service, call it service B. It can also receive the response back from service B and then forward the **response** as an asynchronous message to service C.

However there is no way for the router to send message A to the service C based on the response content from service B because by that point the response from service B (rather than message A) will be the current message being processed.

Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I started to explore the [IOperationInvoker](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/17/wcf-extensibility-ioperationinvoker.aspx) to intercept the operation before it is actually invoked

- At that point, you might have to manually establish channels to the other services to gather your information.
- The pain point could be de-serializing the message object available as a part of input array to the invoker. Converting your objects back to a message as an output.
- Dealing with the async scenario.

I have a similar scenario to deal with and any pointers on how you solved the problem would be highly appreciated.

Best option would be for the "RoutingService" to NOT be a sealed class - this way, we can create our own service and implement the contract we want and override the action.